# What syntax should be used for reading the final row in an Array on the Mapping tab on the Copy Data activity in Azure Data Factory / Synapse?

Tags: arrays, azure, azure-data-factory, pipeline, data-mapping

I'm using the copy data activity in Azure Data Factory to copy data from an API to our data lake for alerting & reporting purposes. The API response is comprised of multiple complex nested JSON arrays with key-value pairs. The API is updated on a quarter-hourly basis and data is only held for 2 days before falling off the stack. The API adopts an oldest-to-newest record structure and so the newest addition to the array would be the final item in the array as opposed to the first.

My requirement is to copy only the most recent record from the API as opposed to the collection - so the 192th reading or item 191 of the array (with the array starting at 0.)
Due to the nature of the solution, there are times when the API isn't being updated as the sensors that collect and send over the data to the server may not be reachable.

The current solution is triggered every 15 minutes and tries a copy data activity of item 191, then 190, then 189 and so on. After 6 attempts it fails and so the record is missed.

[current pipeline structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kzder.png)

I have used the mapping tab to specify the items in the array as follows (copy attempt 1 example):

`$['meta']['params']['sensors'][*]['name']`  
`$['meta']['sensorReadings'][*]['readings'][191]['dateTime']`  
`$['meta']['sensorReadings'][*]['readings'][191]['value']`

Instead of explicitly referencing the array number, I was wondering if it is possible to reference the last item of the array in the above code?
I understand we can use 0 for the first record however I don't understand how to reference the final item. I've tried the following using the 'last' function but am unsure of how to place it:

`$['meta']['sensorReadings'][*]['readings'][last]['dateTime']`  
`$['meta']['sensorReadings'][*]['readings']['last']['dateTime']`  
`last['meta']['sensorReadings'][*]['readings']['dateTime']`  
`$['meta']['sensorReadings'][*]['readings']last['dateTime']`

[image: Example of my API response]

Any help or advice on a better way to proceed would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `last` function should do that for you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#last

Comment: Thank you @wBob for your response. Could you advise on how to incorporate the 'last' function into the code above please? I've updated my question to demonstrate what I've tried to date.

Comment: Yeah you probably can't do it in the Mapping.  A more common approach would be to land the data in a data lake in its raw format, i.e. everything, then run a process over it to transform / filter, e.g. Lookup or Notebook etc.  Alternately can you call your API with a Web activity?  That would bring the json into the data pipeline where `last` would definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you call your API with a Web activity?  If so, this pulls the API result into the data pipeline and then apply ADF functions like `last` to it.

A simple example calling the [UK Gov Bank Holidays API](https://www.api.gov.uk/gds/bank-holidays/#bank-holidays):

[image]

This returns a resultset that looks like this:

```
{
    "england-and-wales": {
        "division": "england-and-wales",
        "events": [
            {
                "title": "New Year’s Day",
                "date": "2017-01-02",
                "notes": "Substitute day",
                "bunting": true
            },
            {
                "title": "Good Friday",
                "date": "2017-04-14",
                "notes": "",
                "bunting": false
            },
            {
                "title": "Easter Monday",
                "date": "2017-04-17",
                "notes": "",
                "bunting": true
            },
            ... etc
```

You can now apply the last function to is, e.g. using a `Set Variable` activity:

```
@string(last(activity('Web1').output['england-and-wales'].events))
```

Which yields the last bank holiday of 2023:

```
{
    "name": "varWorking",
    "value": "{\"title\":\"Boxing Day\",\"date\":\"2023-12-26\",\"notes\":\"\",\"bunting\":true}"
}
```

Or

```
@string(last(activity('Web1').output['england-and-wales'].events).date)
```

Comment: Thank you @wBob for your explanation above. I have tried with your example and it works great, however I'm having issues when using my API - possibly as it's a nested json array and I'm not sure how the formatting of the mapping expression works. Also regarding the variable, do you set this as a string or an array?

My expression is as follows:
@string(last(activity('Get API Data').output['meta'].sensorReadings).readings)

But I'm getting almost all of the data returned as opposed to the last record for each sensor.